# Hindi font support for android 2.2 version and below

Tags: android, fonts, hindi

I am working on a app,which has to display hindi font, but the same is not happening when I try to do that in android 2.2 and below versions. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are trying to do that?

Comment: @blackcrow I have textviews and trying to use the typeface like this, 'tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/DVYG0NTT.TTF");photos_head.setTypeface(tf);photos_head.setText("/*hindi data from xml*/");'

Comment: Looks like your code is good. What problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the fonts at [Chetan Gole's Blog post](http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/).

Comment: Ya,I am using the same font(droidHindi)from that blog with different name(for my convenience),But I am gettin some memory issue.

Comment: Edit you question and add the issues you are facing include all messages in Logcat.